# Matlab: appending cell array

Tags: matlab

I have 10 binary files, each storing a list of numbers. I want to load each file in turn, and then append a cell array `y` with the numbers in that file. So if each file contains 20 numbers, I want my final cell to be 10x20. How do I do this? The following code does not work:

```
for i=1:10
    % Load an array into variable 'x'
    y = {y x}
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a minor modification to your code:

```
y = cell(1,10); %// initiallize if possible. Not necessary
for ii = 1:10 %// better not use i as a variable (would override imaginary unit)
    %// Load an array into variable 'x'
    y{ii} = x; %// fill ii-th cell with x.
    %// Or use y{end+1} = x if you haven't initiallized y        
end
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that works fine if I know how many files there are, but what if I don't? How can I continuously append an element to the cell array? (I know that there are simple ways to find out the number of files, but I'm more interested in the method for dynamic cell allocation.)

Comment: Just remove first line. Initiallization is not necessary; it is just recommended to speed up code

Comment: Ah, thanks. Finally, suppose this is not in a loop and at some point I want to append a cell element to the end of the cell array, without having the index, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading strictly numbers and want an array (rather than cells), this could work:

```
% read CSV numbers from file into array
temp = {};
out = [];
for i=1:10
   % my example files were called input1.txt, input2.txt, etc
   filename = strcat('input', num2str(i), '.txt');
   fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
   temp = textscan(fid,'%d','delimiter',',');      
   out(i,:) = cell2mat(temp);
   fclose(fid);
end
```

'out' is a 10x20 array